# Format Exception in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void GridEmp_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            //Task 2 for Add button
            if(e.CommandName == "add")
            {
                //code to display footer row
                GridEmp.FooterRow.Visible = true;
            }
            else if(e.CommandName=="save")
            {
                //code to insert a record
                TextBox txtEno = (TextBox)GridEmp.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmpNo");
                TextBox txtEname =(TextBox)GridEmp.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmpName");
                TextBox txtEsal = (TextBox)GridEmp.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmpSal");

                int eNo = int.Parse(txtEno.Text);
                string eName = txtEname.Text;
                double eSal = double.Parse(txtEsal.Text);
                cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Emp values(@eNo,@eName,@eSal)");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eNo", eNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eName", eName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eNo", eSal);
                conn.Open();
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                if(i==1)
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Record in inserted";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Not inserted";
                }
                BindEmp();
            }
```

I don't see any error in the code, but still I'm getting Format Exception even I used Parse to convert from string to int. Can someone help me where exactly I did mistake !

[image]

Comment: Well what's the value of `txtEno.Text`? You'll probably find that it's not something that can be parsed as an int.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing is raised when you try to convert a string that cannot be parsed into an `int` value. Since you haven't mentioned the value of `txtEno.Text`, I cannot know specifically what it is. Whatever it is however, it cannot be converted into an `int`.

So your mistake was that you didn't account for users entering invalid values.

You should modify your code to use [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead. This will allow you to handle invalid data inputted by mistake without the program crashing:

```
TextBox txtEno = (TextBox)GridEmp.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmpNo");
int eNo;
bool eNoIsValid = int.TryParse(txtEno.Text, out eNo);
if (!eNoIsValid)
{
    // Handle invalid input.
}
```